# How can I arrange column order in a grid view when I am binding it with a list object?

Tags: c#, windows

How to arrange column in my data grid view for windows application when I am binding it with a list type object?

In db I have 2 many queries to fetch the data so that I can not change I need to make it at form level please suggest.

Following is a small code for this

```
public void FillGrid(string DriverID)
{
     grdOrderByDriver.DataSource = cOrder.GetOrderDetailByDriver(int.Parse(DriverID));
     double sum = 0.0;
     SetGird();
     sum = CalculateOrderTotal(sum);
}
```

`GetOrderDetailByDriver` returns object of

```
BindingList<cOrder> lstOrderByDriver = new BindingList<cOrder>();
```

Comment: You even didn't specify what kind of grid do you use...

Comment: C# gridview..that i get in 4.0 for ..

Comment: What type `cOrder.GetOrderDetailByDriver` returns?

Comment: it returns a list holding list<order> objects..

Comment: it returns   BindingList<cOrder> lstOrderByDriver = new BindingList<cOrder>(); object

Comment: Can't help you with that, never worked with ASP.NET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by "arrange"?

If your intention is to change the column order, you have two possibilities:

- change the DisplayIndex of your column
- if your columns are autogenerated, change the order of the properties in cOrder

If by "arrange" you mean sorting, then you need to implement a SortableBindingList (since the BindingList does not support sorting) like this:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31418/Implementing-a-Sortable-BindingList-Very-Very-Quic